# Gradle doesn't download JDBC drive Postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, gradle

I am using Eclipse + Gradle and Postgresql to develop an example project, I added the dependency JDBC driver on files build.gradle but Gradle doesn't download JDBC driver, what would can it be?

That is my code

```
plugins {

    id 'java-library'
}

repositories {

    mavenCentral()
    
}

dependencies {

    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.8.1'

    api 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'

    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:30.1.1-jre'
    
    // dependency JDBC drive Postgresql
    implementation group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '42.4.0'    
}

tasks.named('test') {

    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: is there any error message output? @JGSILVA

Comment: yes... 

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver
 at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
 at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
 at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:375)
 at util.ConnectionFactory.getConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:18)`

Comment: Try to change your `implemention` to `api` keywords, the implemention just works for current module. @JGSILVA or try to open your local grade cache folder to find out whether the gradle download the dependencies jar file.   For example: `api "org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.23"`, my file store here: `/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.postgresql/postgresql`

Comment: `> Task :wrapper

> Task :init
Get more help with your project: https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/sample/sample_building_java_libraries.html

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 14s
2 actionable tasks: 2 executed

CONFIGURE SUCCESSUL in 421ms
> Task :nothing UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSUL in 6s`

Gradle downloaded the dependency but the error persist. Shows this message quickly and back to the first error message posted above

Comment: does the postgresql jar downloaded? did you fixed this problem? @JGSILVA

Comment: yes it downloaded, but the error persists and the JDBC drive does not appear in eclipse, but it is in the Gradle directory `C:\Users\Developer\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.postgresql\postgresql`

Comment: maybe you can try it with the Intellij Idea. @JGSILVA